# Special characters missing when printing directories from command prompt to text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, special-characters, command-prompt, symbols

I am trying to print lists of directories. I have a lot of folders with special characters and symbols. Lots of foreign letters with accent marks like É. When I do `DIR` in CMD, everything looks fine. But when I print to a file `dir >> output.txt` the special characters are missing in the text file. Some are replaced by ? instead. How can I prevent this and have all characters appear in the text file?

Comment: If you copy&paste the text from `output.txt` into another text editor, do the correct characters appear?

Comment: what is your codepage? do `chcp` from `cmd` to see your codepage.

Comment: @Adriano Yes, when copying and pasting into Notepad the characters are all there

Comment: @Gerhard Active code page: 437

Comment: Before the dir command change your code page to 1252.

Comment: then open `cmd` then do `chcp 65001` press enter, then do your `dir>>output.txt` again.

Comment: @Gerhard It works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Before running your `dir` command, run this :

```
CMD/U
```

you will be abble to export special characters in the txt file.